# Where to start if there is no version control of any kind -Intersystems Cache

Tags: intersystems

Code has been developed and deployed from environments for many years without any source control. Now a source control solution is needed. I am thinking of using Git. I know the hooks have to be written and I am fine with that. But where do we start?

Comment: You start by setting up or finding a 3. party service to host the repository and then add your code to it, and train your developers how to use it. What kind of information are you really looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using recent (2016.2+) versions of Caché, consider using [Atelier](http://intersystems.com/atelier) as IDE. Atelier is based on Eclipse, so you can use any existing source control plugins for Eclipse.

If your IDE is Studio the good start is

- Read "Using Studio Source Control Hooks"
  http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSTD_Hooks
- Examine sample class Studio.SourceControl.Example in SAMPLES
  namespace and adjust it for your needs.
- Google and search on [community.intersystems.com](http://community.intersystems.com). It is very popular
  topic.